# Best way to play animations synchronously?

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

My Application will download data from the web, whenever the user will trigger. The user can trigger multiple downloads.
Each download is listed in a stack panel an a busy icon is shown on each item which is rotating while downloading.

```
<Image x:Name="rotatingCircle" Source="{StaticResource busy_icon}" Height="30" RenderTransformOrigin=".5,.5" Visibility="Visible">
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform x:Name="AnimatedRotateTransform" Angle="0" />
            </Image.RenderTransform>
            <Image.Style>
                <Style>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="Image.IsEnabled" Value="True">
                            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Angle"
                                From="0"
                                To="360"
                                Duration="0:0:1"
                                RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </Trigger.EnterActions>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Image.Style>
        </Image>
```

How can I synchronise the animation, so that every circle is rotating with the same angle, regardless when it was started?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case it was enough to store Storyboards in a list. Every time when a animated icon was added I simply iterate through all Storyboards and started them again (sb.Begin()).
There is a small flicker, because every element is starting at the initial position, but they are running absolut synchronously.